# Как импортировать в unity модель fbx (из skp)

Tags: unity3d, fbx, форматы-файлов

Есть модель арены. Изначально она была в формате skp, но я конвертировала ее в fbx. И unity на нее не ругается.
[image]

Но я ругаюсь на unity, так как когда я ее переношу на сцену, она как будто пустая. Если использовать онлайн просмотр fbx файлов - тоже ничего не показывает. При этом изначальный skp файл в sketch up открывается.
Как перенести модель skp/fbx в unity? И почему fbx viewer ничего не показывает? Это проблема в fbx файле? Как тогда нормально преобразовать skp в fbx?

Заранее спасибо!

Настройки модели в unity:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасите меня, пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуй другой конвертор

Comment: Уже штук пять перепробовала((. Попробую еще. Спасибо за попытку помочь

Comment: А можете посоветовать какой-нибудь проверенный конвертор?

Comment: Вы используете скетчап, чтобы создать эту skp модель или вы её скачали? Если первое то можно экспортировать в fbx сразу из приложения, но возможно это только в про версии, или можно экспортировать в dae или какой то другой вариант и попробовать конвертировать уже его.

Comment: Получилось!!! Большое спасибо! Очень выручил